# Excel formula question, segregation of duties rules

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of roles and need to create the segregation rules comprised of two columns with every pair combination of the roles. I've been advised that this will be a regular task and the number of roles will range between 50 - 100.

I will be provided with an excel with a list of roles in column A and I must provide columns B and C.

### Input-Column A

1. Actor
2. Pilot
3. Dancer
4. Police officer

### Expected Output

| Column B-Output 1 | Column C-Output 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Actor | Pilot |
| Actor | Dancer |
| Actor | Police officer |
| Pilot | Dancer |
| Pilot | Police officer |
| Dancer | Police officer |

In brief, a person can be given ANY role however they may not have any other role assigned to them.
Our system doesn't have a 'one role per person' criteria so we're stuck doing manual roles.

Currently I've been able to make column B (output 1) using https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1897-excel-repeat-cell-value-x-times.html

**Can someone help me figure out how to create column C**

**OR if you have a way to create B + C simultaneously I'm more than happy to use it.**

Requirements for the output is -

1. Must be done in excel only
2. There must not be any duplicates in a single rule (B<>C)

e.g. Actor - Actor = not allowed

3. The B-C and C-B is not allowed

e.g. Actor - Pilot is acceptable

e.g. Actor - Pilot and Pilot - Actor is not allowed

4. The first role in B must be the same as the first role in A.
   C must correspond accordingly with the second entry in A
5. This must be expandable/repeatable for a varied number of roles
6. No macros allowed
7. Some roles may have multiple words associated
   example "Actor A" or "City Police Officer" etc.

I need to submit B + C only so you can use as many additional rows/columns as required.

I've been told that copy pasting is how 'everyone else' has done it, but I feel that they were happy to waste the whole day doing this task.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you want the first role to have each role except it's own and for every next role you want each role except it's own and any previous roles.

When using Microsoft 365 you could use:

```
=LET(r,    A1:A4,
     rw,   ROWS(r)-1,
     m,    rw-SEQUENCE(rw,,0),
     rw_1, DROP(REDUCE(0,m,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(y)^0+TAKE(x,-1)))),1),
     rw_2, REDUCE(2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rw_1)-1,,2),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,IF(INDEX(rw_1,y)=INDEX(rw_1,y-1),TAKE(x,-1)+1,INDEX(rw_1,y)+1)))),
HSTACK(INDEX(r,rw_1),INDEX(r,rw_2)))
```

rw_1 calculates the row number of the roles times any next to roles that come after the current.

rw_2 calculates the row numbers of these roles that come after the current.

Example of the formula with larger range:
[image]

*You may consider replacing `A1:A4` with `FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")` so it adapts the size of the used range in column A. There should not be any other data in the column then.*